# add listitem with value of input

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I've been working on a sortable tree list for our customers to organize their website. Customers can add/drag and remove pages.

To add a page they have to click "add page", this will open a dialog.

What I want to achieve is for them to be able to type in the name of the page you want to add and when you press "save" a list item with that name should be added on the bottom of the list.

dialog jquery:

```
           $(function() {
                    $("#dialog").dialog({
                            autoOpen: false,
                            show: {
                                    effect: "fade",
                                    duration: 500
                            },
                            hide: {
                                    effect: "fade",
                                    duration: 500
                            }
                    });

                    $("#opener").click(function() {
                            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
                    });
                    $("#closer").click(function() {
                        //add list item with value of input
                            $("#dialog").dialog("close");

                    });
            });
```

dialog html:

```
       <div id="dialog" title="Pagina toevoegen">
            <form>
                    Pagina: <input type="text" name="page"><br>

            </form>
            <button id="closer">opslaan</button>
    </div>
```

The part I don't know is how do I get the text the user typed in the dialog and put it on a list item.

I want to add that I am a second year student working as an intern. I'm doing my best to learn. this website and it's users have already tought me a lot.

I hope someone can help me(and maybe others stuck in a similar situation).

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the Stackoverflow ;)
Simplest thing you can do is grab [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) from input when you click button#closer and then [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) value to some html list that you have somewhere in your page.

```
$("#closer").click(function() {
                    //add list item with value of input

                        value_from_dialog_input = $("#dialog input").val();
                        $('#your_list_id').append(value_from_dialog_input);
                        $("#dialog").dialog("close");


});
```

Comment: first of all, thanks for the fast reaction and for welcoming me :D. Also your answer did the trick, I had indeed searched on .val() but i must have done something wrong. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the opposite type of quotes than what you're using in your HTML. So since you're using double quotes in your attributes, surround the code with single quotes.

```
$("#dialog").append('<li><a href="/user/messages"><span class="tab">Some text</span></a></li>');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. It did help me with another thing :)

Comment: what kind of another help ?